# Rail::Engine using Rails::Application styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, rails-engines

How my Rails Engine when installed on an Rails Application will use the Application stylesheets?

Now, when the engine is instaled, they no have styles. I try to override the [engine]/layouts/application to use my "application" stylesheet, but i thing this is the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this setting up the application layout :) on `application_controller.rb`

```
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    layout 'layouts/application' 
  end
```